# Apache Flink: REST API retrieve metric values

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I started Latency tracking and passed the `/jobs/metrics` of the REST API. Obtained the following information:

`{"id":"latency.source_id.cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2.operator_id.e5ebb093256018a0621f548fbe118f8a.operator_subtask_index.0.latency_p75"},
{"id":"lastCheckpointExternalPath"},              {"id":"latency.source_id.cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2.operator_id.55785f9edccd37ac9093dea77018f09d.operator_subtask_index.0.latency_max"},       {"id":"latency.source_id.cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2.operator_id.55785f9edccd37ac9093dea77018f09d.operator_subtask_index.0.latency_p999"},
  .....`

**Q：** Why aren't the specific values displayed? How should I use the API correctly?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

See the [doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#latency-tracking).

`/jobs/metrics` return the metrics' id, you need query with job id and metric id:

```
GET taskmanagers/ABCDE/metrics?get=metric1,metric2
```

to get values like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "metric1",
    "value": "34"
  },
  {
    "id": "metric2",
    "value": "2"
  }
]
```

Comment: What you are talking about is JVM related metrics information returned by `GET /jobmanager/metrics`, not the latency metrics information returned by `/jobs/metrics`.

Comment: His answer also applies to /jobs/metrics.